# Jquery variables variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

There exist some concept like variables variable to print variable names or call functions dynamically:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jquery isn't a language, it's a library. Javascript (EcmaScript) is the language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest JavaScript equivalent is [bracket notation](http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html), for example:

```
var obj = { myMethod: function() { alert("Hello!"); } };
var func = "myMethod";
obj[func](); //equal to obj.myMethod();
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Pj3bC/), in JavaScript calling these two is equivalent:

```
object.property
object["property"];
```

And the latter allows you to use a variable, to get any property or method you want.

To be clear this is a JavaScript behavior, there's nothing specific to jQuery about it.

Answer (score 7):

In javascript you can use a similar aproach.

```
$a = "hello";
$['hello'] = 'world';
$[$a];
alert($a + " " + $[$a]); // alerts "hello world"
```

See in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhUsZ/).